# How to stream audio using HttpResponse

Tags: php, httpresponse, audio-streaming

I have recently created a Digital Ocean server and on it, I have installed the pecl_http-1.7.6 PHP extension so that I may write PHP scripts that can respond to http requests.

I am curious about two different things. The first part, is, how does someone stream data via PHP code using HttpResponse? I know there are 'setStream' methods and such, which leads me to believe that you can set up a data stream using an http request.

The second part, is, how will I go about streaming audio data once I can set up a stream in the general case? I am most likely going to use Java to perform http requests on my server, which I have already tested and it has worked.

Comment: Have you installed PECL HTTP?  Are you trying to stream from the request or to the response?  You don't necessarily need that PECL module, but there is nothing stopping you from installing and using it if you choose to do so.

Comment: I am using pecl_http-1.7.6 as a PHP extension. I am trying to stream audio data from my web server running PHP to any number of clients that make any number of http requests. How would I go about doing this? Is there a library for this?

Comment: `echo` is all you need.  No library necessary.